# How can I add every element in a list of unequal length?

Tags: python, list, function

So here is a code I have which attempts to add every element in a list irrespective of their lengths.

```
def elem_sum(lst1, lst2):
   f_len = len(lst1) - (len(lst2) - 1)
   for i in range(0, len(lst2), 1):
      if f_len - i >= len(lst1):
         break
      else:
         lst1[i] = lst1[i] + lst2[i]
   return lst1
```

When certain inputs such as `elem_sum([1, 2, 3], [10, 20])` are provided,

the output correctly returns `[11, 22, 3]`

While other inputs such as `elem_sum([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40])`

the output returns error.

What should I change here to make sure my code works for any given set of inputs??

Comment: There is a possible shortcut. `[sum(t) for t in itertools.zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=0)]`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I wondered the same thing at first, but I think the example output `[11, 22, 3]` in the question makes it sufficiently clear.

Comment: Your convoluted  `f_len` usage makes no sense whatsoever. For example, `elem_sum([1, 2, 3], [10])` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: On a side note, I'm having a difficult time understanding what `f_len` is for. I think you are trying to check if `i` goes beyond the length of `list1` so that you don't index it and cause an error. If so, you should just do so directly: `if i >= len(lst1)`. Now you can get rid of `f_len`.

Answer (score 3):

One option that may be worth considering is to make use of an existing library routine to give you pairs of numbers from lists of unequal lengths. The `zip_longest` function in the `itertools` package will do this, giving a sequence of tuples. After the end of one of the lists is reached, the missing values will be filled out using the specified fill value, which defaults to `None` but you can pass your own fill value.

For example,

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]

for t in zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=0):
    print(t)
```

gives:

```
(1, 10)
(2, 20)
(3, 30)
(0, 40)
```

So you could just write your function to use a list comprehension that calculates the sum of each of these tuples:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def elem_sum(lst1, lst2):
    return [sum(t) for t in zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=0)]

print(elem_sum([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40]))
```

which gives:

```
[11, 22, 33, 40]
```

Provided that you are not using a very old version of Python, the `itertools` package is in the standard Python library, so you do not need to install any add-on packages.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check the lengths and swap the lists if needed:

```
    def elem_sum(lst1, lst2):
        # Swap if needed
        if len(lst1) < len(lst2):
            lst1, lst2 = lst2, lst1

        f_len = len(lst1) - (len(lst2) - 1)
        for i in range(0, len(lst2), 1):
            if f_len - i >= len(lst1):
                break
            else:
                lst1[i] = lst1[i] + lst2[i]
        return lst1
```